# Add marker to map fragment from onFocusChange() method of Edit Text

Tags: android

I want to do all of this

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
     //Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
   LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.863184,151.189420);
    mMap.addMarker(new 
MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(null).draggable(true));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,17f));
}
```

from the onFocusChange method of an Edit Text, but the onFocusChange method isn't passed a GoogleMap variable like the onMapReady method is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are passing wrong context in the argument.

Use it as below:

```
mapFragment.getMapAsync(YourActivityName.this);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to drop a marker and have the map show that location, from the onFocusChanged method of an Edit text. In the OnMapReady method there is GoogleMap variable called googleMap which seems to come from the OnMapReadyCallback class. How do I make that variable accessible to the onFocusChanged method of my Edit Text? Or create a new Googlemap variable that somehow links to that fragment?

Comment: Start another question for that problem. Or edit your existing question with more code. No one can understand such problem statement without code. And if the answer helped you mark it as expected or atleast upvote it.

Comment: I sorted it out. I needed to leave the marker code in the onMapReady method, and put the "mapFragment.getMapAsync(YourActivityName.this);" in the onFocusChange method of my Edit Text. I'm marking Zankrut's contribution above as the answer as it helped me the most